# HTML5 <fieldset> <legend> wrapped around an editable table grid?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm marking up a <table> grid that will display values that can be updated by the user. Once the user click on a <td> jQuery will make the text inside the <td> editable - by means of an input tag. Should this table be wrapped in a <fieldset> with an accompanying <legend>?

I'm thinking it should; because it will contain inputs once the user clicks on it but my colleague disagrees...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, as long as you are sticking to the rules of validation, a `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` set of tags is only useful if they make semantic sense. Is there anything you need to hang off those tags? Do they provide you any benefit, vs. the additional markup that is put into the page as a result (not to mention, additional styles that must be written to accommodate them, if necessary)?

I like to fall on the side of caution and restraint when it comes to adding tags to my markup. Depending on your use case, that may or may not be applicable to your needs. You have to follow needs, first... if you can accomplish what you need with less markup, that will make maintenance and upkeep easier over the long run.